# Не могу обновить SSL сертификат через certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl, utf-8, letsencrypt, certbot

```
nginx 1.18
certbot 0.31.
ubuntu 16.04
```

Установил certbot на сервер, все отлично, сертификаты все работают. Но команда `certbot renew --dry-run`
выдаёт ошибку, как я понял,  связанную с кодировкой utf-8.

Консоль:

```
:~# certbot renew --dry-run
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/junnote.com.ua.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
Attempting to renew cert (junnote.com.ua) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/junnote.com.ua.conf produced an unexpected error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 930: invalid continuation byte. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/junnote.com.ua/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/junnote.com.ua/fullchain.pem (failure)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

лог файл:

```
2020-05-23 21:22:23,290:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.31.0
2020-05-23 21:22:23,291:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['--dry-run']
2020-05-23 21:22:23,292:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#nginx,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,PluginEntryPoint#webroot)
2020-05-23 21:22:23,305:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 20
2020-05-23 21:22:23,307:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2020-05-23 21:22:23,321:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator <certbot.cli._Default object at 0x7f6e31335898> and installer <certbot.cli._Default object at 0x7f6e31335898>
2020-05-23 21:22:23,321:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var dry_run=True (set by user).
2020-05-23 21:22:23,321:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var server={'staging', 'dry_run'} (set by user).
2020-05-23 21:22:23,321:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var dry_run=True (set by user).
2020-05-23 21:22:23,321:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var server={'staging', 'dry_run'} (set by user).
2020-05-23 21:22:23,322:DEBUG:certbot.cli:Var account={'server'} (set by user).
2020-05-23 21:22:23,334:INFO:certbot.renewal:Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
2020-05-23 21:22:23,335:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator nginx and installer nginx
2020-05-23 21:22:23,362:WARNING:certbot.renewal:Attempting to renew cert (junnote.com.ua) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/junnote.com.ua.conf produced an unexpected error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 930: invalid continuation byte. Skipping.
2020-05-23 21:22:23,365:DEBUG:certbot.renewal:Traceback was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 452, in handle_renewal_request
    main.renew_cert(lineage_config, plugins, renewal_candidate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1187, in renew_cert
    installer, auth = plug_sel.choose_configurator_plugins(config, plugins, "certonly")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 228, in choose_configurator_plugins
    installer = pick_installer(config, req_inst, plugins, installer_question)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 32, in pick_installer
    config, default, plugins, question, (interfaces.IInstaller,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 106, in pick_plugin
    verified.prepare()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 251, in prepare
    return [plugin_ep.prepare() for plugin_ep in six.itervalues(self._plugins)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 251, in <listcomp>
    return [plugin_ep.prepare() for plugin_ep in six.itervalues(self._plugins)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 132, in prepare
    self._initialized.prepare()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_nginx/configurator.py", line 152, in prepare
    self.parser = parser.NginxParser(self.conf('server-root'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_nginx/parser.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_nginx/parser.py", line 45, in load
    self._parse_recursively(self.config_root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_nginx/parser.py", line 56, in _parse_recursively
    trees = self._parse_files(filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_nginx/parser.py", line 207, in _parse_files
    parsed = nginxparser.load(_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_nginx/nginxparser.py", line 123, in load
    return loads(_file.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 930: invalid continuation byte

2020-05-23 21:22:23,365:ERROR:certbot.renewal:All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
2020-05-23 21:22:23,365:ERROR:certbot.renewal:  /etc/letsencrypt/live/junnote.com.ua/fullchain.pem (failure)
2020-05-23 21:22:23,366:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.31.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1365, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1272, in renew
    renewal.handle_renewal_request(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 477, in handle_renewal_request
    len(renew_failures), len(parse_failures)))
certbot.errors.Error: 1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

Comment: уберите из конфигурационных файлов не-utf8 символы. в частности, видимо, кириллические буквы. вот так найдёте файл(ы), где программа нашла символ `0xc4` (если в кодировке cp1251, то это буква `Д`): `$ LANG=C grep -lrP '\xc4' /etc/nginx`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin You are my hero. Напишите коммент в ответы, я отмечу, ибо почистил nginx.conf от кириллицы и все заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

уберите из конфигурационных файлов не-utf8 символы. в частности, видимо, кириллические буквы.

вот так найдёте файл(ы), где программа спотыкается на символе `0xc4` (если в кодировке cp1251, то это буква `Д`):

```
$ LANG=C grep -lrP '\xc4' /etc/nginx
```